Is there such a thing as 'Nāma-Aparādha' in non-gauḍīya Vaiṣṇava sampradāyas?
This gets thrown around a lot in the gauḍīya community. The concept of 'offensive chanting', that somehow the name we utter is not pure and there are volumes of literature on this but I'm not sure where this idea comes from.
Is this purely a fabrication? or something real recognized by ancient sages and other Vaiṣṇava ācāryas?

Avoiding Nama-aparadha is emphasized more in Gaudiya Vaishnavism since chanting is the chief among its various spiritual practices.
Chanting without offenses is an instruction from the Puranas meant for all Sadhakas regardless of the Sampradaya as reverberation of a Mantra should not be done in an offensive state of mind. So, it is certainly not a fabrication by the Gaudiya Vaishnavas.
In the Sanatkumara Samhita, Lord Sadashiva, while describing to Narada Muni how to chant the Mantra for worshipping Krishna cautions against committing Nama-aparadha.

yac capi bhagavan-nama
su-labham syat kalau yuge
na purna-phala-dam tac ca
tasminn evaparadhinam

In the Kali-yuga the Lord's holy name is easy to attain. Still, the
full result of the holy name does not come to they who commit
offenses (aparādhinām).
aparadha-sahasrani
kritva krishne nirantaram
namasrayas taranty eva
tani sarvani manavah

They who commit thousands of offenses to Lord Krishna, but
nevertheless take shelter of the Lord's holy name, cross beyond all
those offenses.
namni kritvaparadhams tu
yasyanti narakam dhruvam
ittham su-dushkara bhaktih
sukarapi janardane

They who commit offenses (kritvaparadhams) to the holy name go to hell. It is with the
holy name's help that devotion to Lord Hari, which is otherwise so
difficult to attain, is attained very easily.

A similar statement is found in the Shiva Purana Vāyavīya-saṃhitā Chapter 12.

रागद्वेषानृतक्रोधकामतृष्णानुसारि यत् ।
वाक्यं निरयहेतुत्वात्तद्दुर्भाषितमुच्यते ॥ २७ ॥

The utterances that are actuated by passion, hatred, falsehood, anger,
lust and greediness are bad. They cause one’s fall into hell.

